# Prove that: $x^x-y^y\ge(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y$, where $x\ge y>0.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

I want to analyze the following inequality:

> Let $x,y\in\Bbb R^{+}$, then prove that:
> $$x^x-y^y\ge(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y$$
> holds for all $x\ge y$.

I observed that, for possible simplification, dividing both side of the inequality into any of the expressions like $x^x, x^y, y^y, y^x$ doesn't work.

Using the identity $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$ and $y^y=e^{y\ln y}$ doesn't help.

I used the well-known inequality $e^x≥x+1$ and obtained:

$$x^x=e^{x\ln x}≥x\ln x+1$$

or

$$y^y=e^{y\ln y}≥y\ln y+1$$

But, this also doesn't help.

**Some observations:**

> Big problem occurs when, $x=0.002, y=0.001$.
> $$-0.0055≈x^x-y^y\ge(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y≈-0.0068$$

If $x=5,y=4.5$ then: $$(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y≈-0.001<0$$

If $x=5,y=3$ then: $$(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y≈24>0$$

If $x-y=1$, then: $(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y=0$. Thus

$$x^x-(x-1)^{x-1}\ge 0$$

which is correct, since $x>1$.

If $x=y>0$, then the equality trivially holds: $0≥0$

The possible inequality plot is as follows:
[image]

I also include the reverse inequality plot:

$$x^x-y^y<(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y$$

[image]

> How can we analyze this inequality?  This doesn't seem possible without using calculus.

Maybe the inequality is simple.  However, I could not find a good point, unfortunately.  Also, I'm having trouble understanding the first graph that Wolfram Alpha presents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inequality is false in general.
The results in Reza Rajaei's answer show that the inequality holds when $y\geq \frac{1}{e}$.

But conversely, when $y\lt \frac{1}{e}$ there will always be an $x$ making the inequality false. To see why, consider the ratios $f_1(x)=\frac{(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y}{x-y}$ and $f_2(x)=\frac{x^x-y^y}{x-y}$ and let us look at their limit when $x$ tends to $y$ from above.

If we put $\phi(x)=x^x$, then $f_2(x)=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(y)}{x-y}$ tends to $l_2=\phi'(y)=(1+\log(y))y^y$ when $x\to y$ from above.

Next,  we can write

$$
f_1(x) =  \frac{(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y}{x-y} \\ 
= \frac{(x-y)^y}{x-y}\big((x-y)^{x-y}-1\big) 
\sim_{x\to y} \frac{(x-y)^y}{x-y}\log\big((x-y)^{x-y}\big) 
$$

because $u-1\sim \log(u)$ when $u\to 1$. It follows that $f_1(x)\sim_{x\to y} (x-y)^y \log\big(x-y\big)$, and hence that $f_1(x)\to l_1=0$ when $x\to y$ from above.
Now, when $y\lt \frac{1}{e}$, we have $l_1\gt l_2$ and hence $f_1(x) \gt f_2(x)$ when $x$ is close enough to $y$.

When we look at a numerical example, say $y=\frac{1}{3}$, we see that $x$ needs to be VERY close to $y$ (the distance between $x$ and $y$ cannot exceed $10^{-7}$). This explains why the inequality seems true and first sight, and why Wolfram Alpha didn't see the counterexamples.

**UPDATE** With some more work, the following quantitative proof above can be "unrolled" into a quantitative proof with explicit constants, as explained below.

To construct our counterexempale, we choose a $y\lt\frac{1}{e}$, say $y=\frac{1}{3}$.

Above we noticed the qualitative result that $f_2(x)\to l_2$ when $x\to y$. We turn this into a quantitative result as follows. We apply a Taylor bound to $\phi$. Note that $\phi'(x)=(1+\log(x))\phi(x)$ and hence $\phi''(x)=\big(\frac{1}{x}+(1+\log(x))^2\big)\phi(x)$. Now, from $e^u\geq 1+u$ we deduce $e^2\geq 3$ and hence $\log(3)\leq 2$. For $x\in [y,1]$, we then have $|\phi(x)|\leq 1$ and

$$
|\phi''(x)|\leq \big(3+(1+\log(3))^2\big) \leq 3+(1+3)^2=12 \tag{1}
$$

Using the Taylor remainder integral formula $\phi(x)-\phi(y)-\phi'(y)(x-y)=\int_{y}^{x}\phi''(t)\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}dt$, we deduce
$|\phi(x)-\phi(y)-\phi'(y)(x-y)|\leq 12 \frac{(x-y)^3}{6}=2(x-y)^3$. Dividing by $x-y$, we obtain for $x\in [y,1]$,

$$
|f_2(x)-l_2| \leq 2(x-y)^2 \tag{2}
$$

Similarly, we convert the limit $f_1(x)\to 0$ when $x\to y$ into a quantitative result. This part is more complicated because there are several substeps more. We have $f_1(x)=f_3(x)f_4(x)$, where

$$
f_3(x)=(x-y)^y\log(x-y),  \ f_4(x)=\frac{(x-y)^{x-y}-1}{\log((x-y)^{x-y})} \tag{3}
$$

Using the well-known inequality $(*):-1 \leq u\log(u)\leq 0$ for $u\in(0,1]$, we have (putting $u=(x-y)^{\frac{y}{2}}$)

$$
|f_3(x)| =\big|\frac{2}{y}(x-y)^y\log((x-y)^{\frac{y}{2}})\big|=\frac{2(x-y)^{\frac{y}{2}}}{y}|u\log(u)|\leq \frac{2(x-y)^{\frac{y}{2}}}{y}= 6 (x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}} \tag{4}
$$

Similarly, using $(*)$ with $u=x-y$ we deduce $-1 \leq z\leq 0$ where $z=(x-y)\log(x-y)$ ; now the mean value theorem yields $|e^z-1|\leq |z|$, and hence $|(x-y)^{x-y}-1|\leq |(x-y)\log(x-y)|$. Using an argument similar to the proof of (4) above, we have $|(x-y)\log(x-y)|\leq 2\sqrt{x-y}$ and hence

$$
1-2\sqrt{x-y} \leq (x-y)^{x-y} \leq 1 \tag{5}
$$

So if we put $v=(x-y)^{x-y}$, the mean value theorem yields $ 1 \leq \frac{log(v)-\log(1)}{v-1} \leq \frac{1}{1-2\sqrt{x-y}}$ or
$1-2\sqrt{x-y} \leq f_4(x) \leq 1$, and hence

$$
|f_4(x)| \leq 1+2\sqrt{x-y} \tag{6}
$$

Multiplying (4) by (6), we deduce

$$
|f_1(x)|\leq 6 (x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}} (1+2\sqrt{x-y}) =
6(x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}}+12(x-y)^{\frac{2}{3}} \leq 18(x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}} \tag{7}
$$

Combining (2) with (7), we obtain

$$
|f_1(x)-f_2(x)+l_2|\leq 2(x-y)^2+18(x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}} \leq 20(x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}}  \tag{8}
$$

Note that $|l_2|=(log(3)-1)\phi(\frac{1}{3})$, now

$$\log(3)=\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dt}{t}=\sum_{k=1}^8 \int_{1+\frac{k-1}{4}}^{1+\frac{k}{4}}\frac{dt}{t}\geq \sum_{k=1}^8\frac{1}{4+k}=\frac{28271}{27720} \tag{9}$$

and hence $\log(3)-1\geq\frac{551}{27720}\geq\frac{1}{100}$, on the other hand $\phi(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{3}^{\frac{1}{3}} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ because $\frac{1}{3} \geq \frac{1}{8}$. Finally $|l_2|\geq \frac{1}{200}$, and we deduce from (8) that

$$
f_1(x)-f_2(x) \geq \frac{1}{200} - 20(x-y)^{\frac{1}{6}} \tag{10}
$$

We see then that $f_1(x)\gt f_2(x)$ whenever $x-y\lt \frac{1}{4000^6}$ ; this is the case for example when $x-y=10^{-22}$.

Comment: Thank you. How do you get $$\frac{(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y}{x-y} \\ 
= \frac{(x-y)^x}{x-y}\big((x-y)^{x-y}-1\big) ?$$

Comment: @User Sorry, I meant $(x-y)^y$ not $(x-y)^x$, that was a typo. Fixed now, thanks

Comment: Not problem..If it is possible, can you provide an exact counterexample pair $(x,y)?$ This would deserve bounty more than $50$.

Comment: very nice!!! +1

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: @User Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I added a proof that $(x=\frac{1}{3}+10^{-22},y=\frac{1}{3})$ is a counterexample pair. The computations are somewhat long and painful, but they are checkable entirely by hand, without a computer.

Comment: Thanks. I think the question turns to disprove the inequality, since the obvious numbers don't exist, this seems a good challenge.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a partial solution which covers your examples, I think.

---

For $x\ge 1$, define $f(t)=x^t-(x-y)^t$, then $f'(t)=x^t\ln x-(x-y)^t\ln (x-y)\ge0$, which means $f(t)$ is an increasing function for $t\ge0$ and $x\ge1$. Hence:

$$f(x)\ge f(y)\implies x^x-(x-y)^x\ge x^y-(x-y)^y \ge y^y-(x-y)^y$$$$\implies x^x-y^y\ge(x-y)^x-(x-y)^y.$$

---

Another easy case is $x\ge 2y$. In this case $x-y\ge y$, and we have $(x-y)^y\ge y^y$ and $x^x\ge (x-y)^x.$

---

**EDIT:**

Another easy case is when $1\gt x\gt y\ge \frac {1}{e} $. In this case $0\lt x-y \lt1,$ so $(x-y)^x\le (x-y)^y$ because $f(t)=(x-y)^t$ is a decreasing function. Therefore, if $1\gt x\gt y\ge \frac {1}{e} $;
$$x^x-y^y\ge0 \ge (x-y)^x- (x-y)^y; $$

because $x^x$ is an increasing function when $x\ge \frac {1}{e}.$

---

Answer (score 3):

*Remark*: I found that the desired inequality is false several hours before @Ewan Delanoy posted his answer. I was held up by something. I post my answer as well.

Consider the case $x > y$ and $y < 1$. Let $z = x - y > 0$. The desired inequality is written as
$$(y + z)^{y+z} - y^y + z^y - z^{y+z} \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{(y + z)^{y+z} - y^y}{z}
+ \frac{1 - z^z}{z^{1 - y}} \ge 0.$$

For fixed $y\in (0, 1)$, by L'Hopital's rule, we have
$$\lim_{z \to 0^{+}} \frac{1 - z^z}{z^{1 - y}} = 0$$
and
$$\lim_{z \to 0^{+}} \frac{(y + z)^{y+z} - y^y}{z} = y^y(\ln y + 1).$$

Thus, if $\ln y + 1 < 0$, we have
$$\lim_{z \to 0^{+}} \left(\frac{(y + z)^{y+z} - y^y}{z}
+ \frac{1 - z^z}{z^{1 - y}}\right) < 0.$$
Thus, the desired inequality is not true for some $z$ when $y < \mathrm{e}^{-1}$.