# Estimating area below a hyperbola : showing $\log(3)\gt 1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, computational-mathematics

In a recent [answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569882/prove-that-xx-yy-gex-yx-x-yy-where-x-ge-y0/4573396?noredirect=1#comment9625381_4573396), I needed to find an explicit constant rational number $c$ such that $\log(3)\geq c \gt 1$ without using a calculator.
I proceeded using a Riemann sum :

$$\log(3)=\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dt}{t}=\sum_{k=1}^8 \int_{1+\frac{k-1}{4}}^{1+\frac{k}{4}}\frac{dt}{t}\geq \sum_{k=1}^8\frac{1}{4+k}=\frac{28271}{27720} $$

If we look at the complexity of the last step in this computation,
we have a sum of $8$ rational numbers, so this makes $3\times 7$ multiplications, $7$ additions, and $7$ fraction reductions.

Since there are estimates with smaller numbers, such as $\log(3)\gt \frac{12}{11}$, I wonder if there are simpler (calculator-free) proofs.

Perhaps by taking a suitable tangent below the hyperbola to evaluate the area ?

Comment: For this question, do you just want to show that $\log 3 > 1$ as in the title, or find an explicit rational $q$ such that $1 < q < \log 3$? Of course, the former implies that there is *some* rational $q$ that does the job.

Comment: If you only wanted to show that $\ln3>1,$ you could as well use that $e^{-1}>1-\frac11+\frac12-\frac16=\frac13.$

Comment: Incidentally, the tangent at $x = a$ gives a lower bound $\frac{4 (a - 1)}{a^2} < \log 3,$ and the quantity on the left-hand side has a maximum of $1$ at $a = 2$.

Comment: @TravisWillse The title was only intended as a summary, sorry if it misled you. My question is indeed about finding an explicit "witness" rational between $1$ and $\log(3)$, as the first sentence says.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thanks for the clarification. I've modified my answer accordingly, though what's now the first solution there is similar to Anne's, but using the definition of $\operatorname{artanh}$ rather than an infinite series. I've added a second solution using a Dalzell-style integral, which can be useful for giving rational bounds for certain irrational expressions.

Comment: A simpler Riemann sum: using the midpoint rule and the fact that $\ln x$ is concave up, we have $\ln 3 > \frac{1}{3/2} + \frac{1}{5/2} = \frac{16}{15}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\forall y\in(0,+\infty)\quad\ln y=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{2k+1}\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right)^{2k+1}$ hence
$$\ln3>2\left(\frac12+\frac1{3\cdot2^3}\right)=\frac{13}{12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** The Taylor series for $$\log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) = 2 \operatorname{artanh} x$$ is $2\left(x + \frac{1}{3} x^3 + \frac{1}{5} x^5 + \cdots\right)$, with all coefficients nonnegative, so for positive $x$, $$2 \operatorname{artanh x} > 2 x + \frac{x^3}{3} ,$$ and in particular $$\log 3 = 2 \operatorname{artanh} \frac{1}{2} > 2 \left[ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \right] = \frac{13}{12} > 1 .$$

**Solution 2** Alternatively, evaluating a Dalzell-style integral gives
$$0 < \int_0^\sqrt{2} \frac{x^2 (1 - x)^2}{1 + x^2} = \log 3 - \left(2 - \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2}\right),$$
so it suffices to find a rational number between $1$ and $2 - \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2}$, or, by rearranging, a number between $2 \sqrt{2}$ and $3$, but rearranging shows that $\frac{17}{6}$ suffices for the former, and correspondingly $1 < \frac{19}{18} < \log 3$. Probably a more clever choice of integral can reduce the amount of subsequent computation.

**Remark** Incidentally, direct computation shows that the (signed) area over the interval $[1, 3]$ and under the tangent line to the curve $x y = 1$ at $(a, \frac{1}{a})$ is $\frac{4 (a - 1)}{a^2}$, which has a maximum of $1$ (at $a = 2$), hence without modification this method cannot yield an explicit rational between $1$ and $\log 3$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was not to merely prove that $\log3>1.$ If you add the term $x^3/3$ of your developement, your answer will be just another formulation of mine.

Comment: That seems to be OP's aim in the post title, but they mention in the question statement that the original motivation for the question is to find an explicit rational $q$ with $1 < q < \log 3$. Perhaps OP can clarify. As you pointed out in your answer, it's easy to do this by keeping an additional term of the power series.